# CKEditor Inline toolbar misplaced when div height changed

Tags: height, ckeditor, inline, toolbar

When using Inline editing with CKEditor (even on CKEditor's Website demos), if the height of a DIV is changed, the inline toolbar will be misplaced (it will stay at the same place it was before even though the DIV moved) for the DIVs under it.
Is it a known problem, is there a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, there's no official support for such case.

Inline toolbar is positioned by the internal method [layout()](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/floatingspace/plugin.js#L51) called on [focus event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-focus). You can reveal the method on your own and call manually or play with [blurring](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager-method-blur)/[focusing](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager-method-focus) the editor.